# Sharing Google Spreadsheets Privately

Tags: google-sheets

If I share an interactive Google Spreadsheet using `File > Publish to the web...` does this spreadsheet include any personal information from my Google Account (eg. Full Name?)

If it does (somewhere in the docs.google.com hosted page's source code), is there a way to privately share this spreadsheet without this personal data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Publishing to the web doesn't include private information other than the content of the file. The only one file property/meta-data that is shown in a published document is the file name.

## Explanation

In the Google Docs editors argot, "publishing to the web" and "sharing" are two different and independent features. The related help articles are included in the references section.

Usually the Google Docs editors official documentation mention the included features, not the missing ones.

WARNING

While the published spreadsheet doesn't include any private information, this open other means of getting information of your spreadsheet but only to those that know the spreadsheet id.

The spreadsheet URL looks like this:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tcLj7YF8Pp8P63oVzPGakHRV8v2dHPtTuH4icowp1jw/edit#gid=0`

The spreadsheet id is `1tcLj7YF8Pp8P63oVzPGakHRV8v2dHPtTuH4icowp1jw`

The URL of published to the web spreasheet looks like this:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRjpwNxpLAj5BM7iaY7i1rnjOiivClHtAl8YNyuZGvpmh_ZAVrDG6UofS9fygH_WHzlkkbSw1TXPJGY/pubhtml`

AFAIK there is no way to guess a spreadsheet id, so while you keep your spreadsheet private (not shared with anyone) your private information will be kept private.

## References

### Google Docs editors Help articles

- [Sharing files and folders](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822?hl=en)
- [Publish a document, spreadsheet, presentation, or drawing](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en)

Comment: This is incorrect. "Publish to the web" exposes the account email address. Steps to reproduce: (1) Publish a Google sheet "to the web" (2) Copy the sheet ID (3) Look at the sheet JSON data: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/YOUR_PUBLISHED_SHEET_ID/1/public/values?alt=json (4) Check the value at key (json).author[0].email ... you will see that your email address is exposed here.

Comment: @jsejcksn The pusblised to the web spreadsheet doesn't include the spreadsheet id.

Comment: I think that detail is in the spirit of the asker’s question, so it should be included in your answer. He asked about source code which makes me think he wants absolutely no leakage.